# Wrong YouTube thumbnail seen by Facebook Advertisement team

Tags: youtube, thumbnails

I have a really weird issue.
When I publish my YouTube video (1 hour long if that matters) I usually set a Custom thumbnail, which has a fixed amount of text on it, so it corresponds with the advertising guidelines of Facebook.

I have ~16% text on the image. According to the Facebook GRID tool.

All my ads are rejected by Facebook, and the answers I got were, that I have too much text on the thumbnail.

After messaging back-and-forth with the support team, they finally sent me a screenshot of the grid tool, and on their screenshot there's a totally different thumbnail that I'm using.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I used facebook debug tool, to fetch new scrape information for the video.